# Appropriate way to report cox proportional hazards model

Tags: survival, dataset, reporting

I have a dataset of 150 patients and 10 variables. I wanted to run a survival analysis, so I did the following:

- Univariate test (log-rank for my categorical variables, univariate Cox proportional hazard regression for my continuous variables)
- The variables which had a p-value less than 0.2 (arbitrarily assigned) were then selected for my cox proportional hazards model (now 5 variables)
- My model eventually contained only 4 variables

When I am reporting the hazard ratio and 95% confidence intervals, I assume I can only report the HR for the 4 variables which made it into my model. Is that appropriate or should my model contain all 10 variables (even if on univariate analysis they don't seem to be significant). Clinically, you could make an argument that they are all at least important, which leads me to think I should put all of them in my model.

Thanks